# How to use cut command in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have following in one of my shell script.

```
    cut -d'=' -f2`
```

could anyone please describe me,what is happening with this command.

Comment: @EtanReisner I think you mean http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html (^:

Comment: @tripleee Hah! Indeed.

Comment: [explainshell](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=cut+-d%27%3D%27+-f2) is always happy to rtfm for you!

Comment: Taken literally, what is happening with that command would be "Syntax Error", due to the stray back-quote there...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cut` command option:

```
d = delimiter 
f = field column
```

Example:

```
[root@server ~]# cat /tmp/file.txt
field1  =    field2
 A      =       a
 B      =       b
 C      =       c
 D      =       d
 E      =       e
 A      =       B
 A      =       B
 A      =       B
```

`-d"="` define delimiter and `-f2` will extract field2 column

```
[root@server ~]# cat /tmp/file.txt | cut -d"=" -f2
      field2  
        a
        b
        c
        d
        e
        B
        B
        B
```

Comment: does that mean it is saving value to delimiter

Comment: `NO` it will just extract filed. without looking at script hard to say